# Function sometimes returns old values when beeing called twice

Tags: c

I have got an URL encoder which sometimes returns the value from the previous call. But it only happens sometimes...

Caller method of get_encoded_string:

```
char* call_api(const char* api_key, const char* pokerName, const char* message) {

CURL* curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();

char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

/* string builder */
char url[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
snprintf(
    url,
    sizeof(url),
    "%s%s%s%s%s%s",
    "http://xdroid.net/api/message?k=",
    api_key,
    "&t=",
    get_encoded_string(pokerName),
    "&c=",
    get_encoded_string(message));

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
const char* data = "";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

if (res == CURLE_OK) {
    return "success";
}
else {
    return errbuf;
}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Class thats returns previous value:

```
char* get_encoded_string(char* string_to_encode) {

CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

/* convert a string into a URL encoded string */
char* encoded_message = curl_easy_escape(curl, string_to_encode, 0);
curl_free(encoded_message);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
return encoded_message;
```

Example:
call_api gets called with this values:
call_api("api_key", "pokerName","message")
so get_encoded_string gets called with "pokerName" and then with "message"
But sometimes get_encoded_string returns "pokerName" twice.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You are freeing the char* and then returning it. Why do you expect you can use it at all after freeing it?

Comment: @user1937198 okay seems logical. Im not that familliar with c and curl. I thought after using return the method will "stop". Or can i still call "curl_free" after returning?

Comment: its not about the method running, its about the memory. After you call curl_free, you have freed the memory, so you should treat it as inaccessible. The simplest thing here would be to just call curl_easy_escape directly in your call_api method, rather than trying to abstract cleanup that you have to do in the call_api method anyway.

Comment: @user1937198 okay i posted my solution. Does that look good to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <string.h>
#include <Curl/curl.h>
#include "push_notification_api.h"


char* call_api(const char* api_key, const char* pokerName, const char* message) {

    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    /* escape the strings for the API call */
    char url[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
    char *esc_name = curl_easy_escape(curl, pokerName, 0);
    char *esc_message = curl_easy_escape(curl, message, 0);

    /* string builder */
    snprintf(
        url,
        sizeof(url),
        "%s%s%s%s%s%s",
        "http://xdroid.net/api/message?k=",
        api_key,
        "&t=",
        esc_name,
        "&c=",
        esc_message);
    curl_free(esc_name);
    curl_free(esc_message);


    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    const char* data = "";
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res == CURLE_OK) {
        return "success";
    }
    else {
        return errbuf;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: I just saw that maybe i only need curl_easy_init() and curl_easy_cleanup() once. But im not sure atm.

Comment: Your now not cleaning up the returns of the easy_escape at all. Your going to need to do that in call api regardless of how you structure it.

Comment: @user1937198 makes sence. I am curious, because curl_free(char *ptr) expects a pointer. In my case I am saving the curl_escape result in a more complex string (named url). So what do i hand curl_free as a pointer?

Comment: You need explicit variables to hold the allocs: `char url[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE]; char *esc_name = curl_easy_escape(curl, pokerName, 0); char *esc_message = curl_easy_escape(curl, message, 0); snprintf( url, sizeof(url), "%s%s%s%s%s%s", "http://xdroid.net/api/message?k=", api_key, "&t=", esc_name, "&c=", esc_message); curl_free(esc_name); curl_free(esc_message);` Also, given that `curl_easy_cleanup` does nothing to free the strings, you only need _one_ pair of `curl_easy_init/curl_easy_cleanup`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).